# What should i use in shell script to run commands for 300 seconds and then end it

Tags: shell

I would like to put all the commands like this and run the shell script but the while loop seems to be not working :
I wanted the script to run for 300 seconds and then end it. $SECONDS is not giving any time or seems not to be working;What am i doing wrong.Here is what i tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
end=$((SECONDS+300))

while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ] do    
ssh  root@192.168.1.17;sh ver3p7/Serial1.sh 
ssh  root@192.168.1.17;cd ver3p7;python Agent.py 
done
```

Comment: Run `/bin/sh --version` on your system and tell us what it says.  Also, why do you have a semicolon after the IP address in your ssh commands?  Doesn't that defeat the purpose?  Or are you not trying to run Serial1.sh and Agent.py on the remote machine?

Comment: How do you know $SECONDS isn't working? Can you type `echo $SECONDS` and see what happens?

Comment: I did echo $SECONDS and it does not print anything

Comment: I did this /bin/sh --version and got this:
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.Also i am trying to do ssh and run that command on the remote machine. It works fine when i did through the command line. It connects to that remote machine and then runs that script. What is the issue with it.Can you explain briefly what is the mistake in it.